# Adicionar ponto('.') após o 3º caractere

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Tenho um registro com o código original do produto, porém preciso colocar um . (ponto) após o 3º caractere.

**Código original**:   `2022027`

**Como deveria ser**:  `202.2027`

Segue a estrutura da tabela:

```
id
nome
descricao
aplicacao
imagem
codigo_original
data_cadastro
tbl_categoria_id
tbl_empresa_id
```

Agradeço a todos desde já !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que devidir a string como deseja.
LEFT(codigo_original,3) -> Os 3 primeiros caracteres 
SUBSTRING(codigo_original FROM 4) -> Os restantes caracteres
Depois necessita concatenar com o ".".:
CONCAT(LEFT(codigo_original,3),'.',SUBSTRING(codigo_originalFROM 4))

```
UPDATE tabela SET teste=CONCAT(LEFT(codigo_original,3),'.',SUBSTRING(codigo_original FROM 4))
```